# Vaadin Form Validation with BeanFieldGroup

Tags: java, vaadin

In the book of Vaadin I read the following:

> Validating a bean is done with a BeanValidator, which you initialize with the name of the bean property it should validate and add it the the editor field. The validation is done immediately after focus leaves the field. **Bean validators are automatically created when using a BeanFieldGroup**.

So here's my BeanFieldGroup:

```
BeanFieldGroup<OrderSearchCriteria> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<>(OrderSearchCriteria.class);
binder.setItemDataSource(searchCriteria);
```

And this is how I've added validation on my bean:

```
@Min(0)
private BigDecimal minAmount;

@Min(0)
private BigDecimal maxAmount;

@Pattern(regexp = "([a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?")
private String email;
```

Validation is not automatically added as I thought it would. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download an implementation of a bean validator, and then things will start working out of the box.

If you're using maven and want to use hibernate-validator you would simply add a dependency in your pom.xml file like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

References:

- Hibernate validator: http://hibernate.org/validator/
- Versions available in Maven: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator